# django static files getting a 404

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to get django static files working when I visit /static/accept.png it returns a 404. I have the file in project_folder/static

My installed apps has static files included

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

and this is what setting up the static files looks like

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.pardir)
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(PROJECT_PATH)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + STATIC_URL,
)
```

Also I am trying to get this working locally i'm not worried about getting it to work in production yet.

Answer (score 0):

You `PROJECT_PATH` is wrong. It points to one level up of the real project path.

Try these settings:

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused with PROJECT_PATH and BASE_DIR, if you want please print and get the values of both the variables, and get the clear picture that how will your code reach the "static" directory. Then try the code below

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                    STATIC_PATH,
)
```